# undefined is not an object react native AR

Tags: reactjs, react-native, arkit

I am learning to use ViroAR (built on react native) after I import a module and try to call it, I am getting the error:

```
"undefined is not an object(evaluating '(0, format: "jpg", quality: 0.8)}.then')"
```

this error is from trying to use the captureScreen method on the react-native-view-shot module. anyone able to point me in the right direction? I am just trying to capture a screenshot on init as a test.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import captureScreen from "react-native-view-shot";


import {
  ViroARScene,
  ViroText,
  ViroMaterials,
  ViroBox,
  Viro3DObject,
  ViroAmbientLight,
  ViroSpotLight,
  ViroARPlaneSelector,
  ViroAnimations,
  ViroNode
} from 'react-viro';


export default class HelloWorldSceneAR extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    // Set initial state here
    this.state = {
      text: "Initializing AR..."
    };

    // bind 'this' to functions
    this._onInitialized = this._onInitialized.bind(this);
    this._onPlaneSelected = this._onPlaneSelected.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={this._onInitialized}>
        <ViroText text={this.state.text} scale={[.5, .5, .5]} position={[0, 0, -1]} style={styles.helloWorldTextStyle} />
        <ViroARPlaneSelector minHeight={.5} minWidth={.5} onPlaneSelected={this._onPlaneSelected}>
          <ViroBox position={[0, -.25, -1]} scale={[.5, .5, .5]} />
        </ViroARPlaneSelector>
      </ViroARScene>
    );
  }

  _onInitialized() {
    this.setState({
      text: "Hello World!"
    });
    captureScreen({
      format: "jpg",
      quality: 0.8
    })
    .then(
      uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
      error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    );
  }

  _onPlaneSelected() {
    this.setState({
      text: "Selected!"
    });

  }


}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  helloWorldTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#ffffff',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

ViroMaterials.createMaterials({
  grid: {
    diffuseTexture: require('./res/grid_bg.jpg'),
  },
});

ViroAnimations.registerAnimations({
  rotate: {
    properties: {
      rotateY: "+=90"
    },
    duration: 250, //.25 seconds
  },
});

module.exports = HelloWorldSceneAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing [`captureScreen`](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot#capturescreen-android-and-ios-only) wrong. It should be like below.

```
import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";
```

Comment: thanks, however, updated this but still the same issue

Comment: Did you link the library after installing?

Comment: yeah, followed these steps: `yarn add react-native-view-shot` then
`react-native link react-native-view-shot`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting the same error then. I'm sorry